# ie10 only media query

Tags: html, css

The following media query targets both ie10 and 1e11

```
  @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

Is there a way to only target ie10.

Comment: Can you use IE conditional statements? or if you have client info as css class, you could just use that

Comment: @Huangism Disn't IE stop using conditional statements after IE9

Comment: They certainly did stop, I was just testing you! Why do you need only IE10? Maybe there is another approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the property value, `-ms-high-contrast` targets both IE10 and IE11.

IE10+ to be precise.

But I have seen people suggest a rather hacky method as follows.

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   .selector { property:value\9; } }
```

Notice the `\9` part.

Please see the comments section of [this](https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/04/target-internet-explorer-10-11-css/) article.

Comment: you don't actually need the media query bit with the weird `\9`.

Comment: yes.  makes sense that other browsers ignore rules they don’t understand